# How to refresh a BindingGroup?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, listbox

I have a ListBox with an ItemSource bound to a collection of objects that implement IDataErrorInfo. In order to get the items in the ListBox to validate individually, I use a binding group.

```
<ListBox.ItemBindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
            <DataErrorValidationRule/>
        </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
    </BindingGroup>
</ListBox.ItemBindingGroup>
```

This is working great, however the validation is only happening once, and I can't figure out how to make it happen again. Refreshing the ItemsSource binding does not cause validation to refresh as I woud expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was playing around with binding groups today and had the same question, only having used this rule in connection datagrids.  You'll have to fire the group validation using one of its methods like UpdateSources:

```
    void StackPanel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            (sender as StackPanel).BindingGroup.UpdateSources();
    }
```

PS - I was using a StackPanel, so you can experiment with events related to your ListBox.